# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser : Select multiple items

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Here is my problem, i want to get text from HTML using HTML DOM.

```html
<div class="smalldesc">
    <div itemprop="datePublished" class="date">Kamis, 25 Mei 2017 | 14:49 WIB</div>
    <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="author">Oleh : <b></b><b>...</b></div>
</div>
```

The text i want to get is "Kamis, 25 Mei 2017 | 14:49 WIB". Here what i tried :

```
$data->find('div[itemprop=datePublished class=date]',0)
```

and

```
$data->find('div[itemprop="datePublished" class="date"]',0)
```

But i still get null, how do i select two items at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried `find('div.date', 0)->plaintext`

Comment: @Danijel yes, still get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple HTML DOM Parser doesn't provide a feature to select an element with identifying two or more attributes. Saying that, `div[itemprop=datePublished class=date]` is seen a garbage to selector class.

I don't recommend this library at all either while there is built-in, more performative and easy way in parsing DOM: [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dox = new DOMXPath($dom);
$dateEl = $dox->query("//div[@itemprop='datePublished'][@class='date']")->item(0);

echo $dateEl->textContent; // Kamis, 25 Mei 2017 | 14:49 WIB
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/IHfml)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

`$data->find('.date');`

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Maybe a problem loading the webpage?